# Displaying "loading" feedback to the user while ashx handler gets document

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a simple ASPX page which has a list of links to documents which are stored in a SQL Server a database.

When a link is clicked on the page an ASHX handler is called which retrieves the document from the database and serves it up to the user using a binarywrite to the response

For larger documents I would like to present some feedback to the user so that they know that the document is coming. However due to the fact that it is the ashx handler that is downloading the document I am not sure how I would do this.

Comment: take a look at this [Real-Time Progress Bar With ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

Comment: If the type of document is an embedded pdf then you may try to implement the solution in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138232/html-embedded-pdfs-onload