# How to reload pdf embeded in html page

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

I am embedding a pdf document on a HTML5 page using a code similar with:

```
<div style="background: transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat">
    <object height="1250px" width="100%" type="application/pdf" data="aaa.pdf">
       <param value="aaa.pdf" name="src"/>
       <param value="transparent" name="wmode"/>
    </object>
</div>
```

(answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138232/html-embedded-pdfs-onload) question)

At some moment in time I would want to reload the embeded pdf file without reloading the entire page. How can this be made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use javascript to rewrite the innerHTML of the containing div. So give it an id and then when you decide to reload reassign the contents of this div:

```
$('#pdf').html('<object height="1250px" ......</object>');
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I was only changing the "data" attribute (using jQuery) and didn't think to change the entire element...

Comment: I used this solution a little bit shortened: $('#pdf').html($('#pdf').html())

Comment: $("#pdfDoc").replaceWith($("#pdfDoc")); should also do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Put it inside an iframe which you then simply reload. Should be the simplest solution and it will work.

Or try this which might also work

```
<object id="pdfDoc" ...>
    ...
</object>

$("#pdfDoc").replaceWith($("#pdfDoc"));
```